# React html and root height setup to fit in the screen?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this index.html css. So, in Chrome, the website has no scrollbar and it fits into the screen. However, on Safari and Firefox, I have a little tiny gap in the bottom that creates a scrollbar. When I check with the web inspector, it was 100vh. And, even if I change to 100%, it still has a tiny gap in the bottom. Is there any solution for this? Plus, how can I fit this to the mobile environment? I heard that this was intentional but some people have managed to fit the screen by using -webkit-fill-available. However, it does not work in my case

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 50000s ease-in-out 0s,
    color 50000s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition-delay: background-color 50000s, color 50000s;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

My index.html file is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />

    <script>
      google = window.google;
    </script>
  

    <title>Sportties</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add your HTML code into the same snipet so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: And did you mean to use min-height or max-height

Comment: I'd tried with both min and max plus more to see how it would affect the site. But nothing really worked on Safari and Firefox. I dunno why it only works on Chrome